# Editing based on SO reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, edits, meta, privileges

I like to edit posts on SO — not for spelling errors or edit wars — especially when I see people struggling with the English language (I'm not a native English speaker either) or being downvoted because of their poor ability to express themselves. If a question is interesting, I edit to prevent it from being closed.

I miss this on Meta, as I do not have enough reputation to edit. Could or should SO reputation be taken into account for privileges?

Comment: Related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/406/should-rep-requirements-for-actions-be-lowered-on-lower-traffic-so-family-sites/414#414

Comment: Voting to close because suggested edits mostly solve this problem now. Yeah, there's still a review queue for suggestions, but edits don't stay in the queue long in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep participating over here and your rep will be high enough in short order to do the editing.  I'm sure if the SO team sees that after a bit people aren't getting enough rep quickly enough to do these things, they will lower the thresholds, but I just started answering questions and in one day got 150 rep.

You'll see a smaller community here, but probably much more active users.  Also there are a bunch of moderators on this site as well I believe who can take care of that role in the few weeks it takes people to build up rep.

Comment: Granted. It just felt awkward when your used to editing not to be able to.

Answer (score 3):

I have edit rights on SU, but I would not feel comfortable with edit rights on other sites, unless I've earned it (this is especially true for SO and SF). I have to prove I know what I'm talking about before I can actually start editing something that others have worked for.

Answer (score 1):

I miss the retagging and editing too, though I prefer to edit the titles - after all it's the first thing anyone sees so a poor title could lead to fewer views and fewer answers.

We can only work within the rules laid down ultimately by Jeff & the other admins. The amount of rep required for voting up and leaving comments has already been reduced. I guess the others will be reduced if the admins feel it's necessary.

Questions like this bring it to their attention that it might be an issue, but really only in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

As a frequent StackOverflow user, I've gained enough rep to edit posts and I feel helpful, cleaning up titles, typos, hyperlinking cited references that aren't linked and cleaning up code with high levels of tab indentation so that they are actually readable.

I visit the SuperUser site too, but more like 10% of the time I spend on StackOverflow.  I'm miles away from having editing rights on SuperUser.

I would hope that its obvious that I have no intention of defacing superuser (based on my SO rep) thus it would be nice if I could somehow leverage that "trust" on the related sites.

Case in point... I asked this question [ATI Catalyst setting to stretch Windows XP start bar across both displays](https://superuser.com/questions/51289/ati-catalyst-setting-to-stretch-xp-start-bar-across-both-displays) and [Molly provided a good alternative answer](https://superuser.com/questions/51289/ati-catalyst-setting-to-stretch-xp-start-bar-across-both-displays/51319#51319) with 4 references (but none were linked).  Since I had to Google them anyway it would have been easy for me to edit the answer to add the links so that future visitors would benefit from them... but I can't. :-(

Comment: Done, you now have hyperlinks in Molly's answer :)